# How to read the information from RAID's HDD when NAS is broken and HDD are not?

Tags: nas, repair, synology, raid-5

Since my Synology NAS (DS411slim) declared as "hybrid" RAID5 I guess this means "software", the plan should be:

1. I should get Synology DSM 6.2 as virtual machine image from somewhere.
2. Convert each of 4 drives to virtual drives.
3. Mount the virtual machine to those virtual drives.

Am I right?
Where to get the image of DSM 6.2 ? Which tools should be used to create virtual drives of RAID's HDD?

Comment: How do you know that the DS411slim is dead?

Comment: @Giacomo1968  When Power LED is ON Status LED is always OFF, sytem never become avilable in network.  Service man said me that there are no voltage on some chips. Also I see that cooler works very "weakly" (even can stop when I put box aside). So overheat was possible.  Is it a kind of common scenario? Another part of story that service man start talking to me not very convincing assumptions "how complex is to read the RAID" right now without giving me an idea why. I respect serivce workers and going to ask them to repear my DS411slim but it seems to read drives works better DIY

Comment: @Giacomo1968 shortly: I paid for diagnostic

Answer (score 1):

Synology DSM is nothing but a Linux Distro - if you just make the disks available to any modern Linux, it will most likely import the RAID5 into a read-only block device. You can then work through any LVM layer if present.

The easiest thing might be to boot your PC from a Linux USB Stick (Live System) and attach the disks via USB enclosures or docking stations, this might be a lot easier than setting up a VM and importing the disks.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunatly I do not have four docking stations, I have two. I will think.

Comment: What a names of those LVM layer deamons that I should learn? e.g. on lubuntu ? or on microsoft ubuntu?

Comment: If I'm going to use USB stick and one mounted USB enclosure with 4 virtual disk images as files, which format and tool you recommend to use to make those 4 virtual disk images? I hope I can mount those files as drives and this is not very complex.